# Malloc for a single element of a void pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i've to work with generic types. For now INT,FLOAT,DOUBLE,STRING.

Let's see for strings.

My array is defined in the string menu in this way.

```
char** Arr = (char**)malloc(number_of_strings * sizeof(char*));
```

Now i have to copy my BST of strings in this array.
So calling my iterative function

`pAlbero* A` is my pointer to BST node.

`i` is passed by 0.

`size` is my `sizeof(type)`.

Copy is a callback function based on types to copy.

```
void* copia_albero_in_array_ordinato_iter(pAlbero* A, void* Arr, int* i,
    int size, FNCOPY Copy)
{
  pStack* st = NULL;
  pAlbero* T = A;
  void* elemento;
  while (st || T)
  {
    if (T)
    {
      st = push(st, T);
      T = T->sx;
    }
    else
    {
      T = top(st);
      st = pop(st);
      elemento = malloc(size);
      Copy(elemento, T->val);
      copia_dato(Arr, *i, elemento, 0, sizeof(elemento));
      free(elemento);
      T = T->dx;
      *(i) = *(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return Arr;
}

void copia_dato(void* dest, int d_pos, void *source, int s_pos, int dim)
{
  void *dst_addr = dest + (d_pos * dim);
  void *src_addr = source + (s_pos * dim);
  memcpy(dst_addr, src_addr, dim);
}
```

I'm pretty new to C, basically i have allocated memory for my array, but how do i allocate for the single cell of string inside it?
Printing the array works fine.
Thank you in advance and sorry if i'm missing to post something.

---

[update from comment]

Doing

```
Arr[i] = ...
```

gives me:

```
array subscript is not an integer
```

Doing

```
Arr[*i] = ...
```

gives me:

```
[Warning] dereferencing `void *' pointer, 4 invalid use of void expression
```

Comment: You can simply use: `Arr[index] = strdup(charPtrVarHere);`, where `index` is the zero-based element index, and `charPtrVarHere` is a `char*` that points to a string. This will (a) allocate the memory required to hold the string and its terminating NULL, and (b) copy the string into this newly allocated memory. E.g: `Arr[0] = strdup("string1");`, _or_ `char *someStr = "someString"; Arr[0] = strdup(someStr);`

Comment: Doing Arr[i] = ... gives me: "array subscript is not an integer". Doing Arr[*i] = ... gives me: "[Warning] dereferencing `void *' pointer, 4 invalid use of void expression"

Comment: I'm already doing this iteratively copying each node of my bst inside my Array keeping my index i and increasing it on each passage. Fact is i don't know how to malloc the single element inside a void* array.
I repeat, doing Arr[i] or Arr[*i] gives me error.

Comment: Oh well.. doing int j

j = *i;
Arr[j] = malloc(...)

seems working and doing his job fine now.
Don't understand tho why couldn't i do Arr[*i]=malloc(...)
Also i had to pass Arr as double pointed void.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Warning] dereferencing `void *' pointer, 4 invalid use of void expression
```

If you declare

```
..., void * Arr, ...
```

`Arr` is a pointer to `void`, applying the `[]` operator to `Arr` is an implicit dereferencing and would lead  to an object of type `void`. The latter does not exist. That's why the compiler complains.